# compiling litecoin OSX 10.9.1

Tags: boost, architecture, linker, x86-64

I'm trying to compile the Litecoin source (https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin.git). Doing this in windows with VmWare OSX 10.9.1(64bit).

I cloned it and in terminal ran:
    make -f makefile.osx USE_UPNP=-

It spits out this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"boost::program_options::to_internal(std::string const&)", referenced from:
 boost::program_options::detail::basic_config_file_iterator<char>::getline(std::string&) in util.o
 "boost::program_options::detail::common_config_file_iterator::common_config_file_iterator(std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool)", referenced from:
 boost::program_options::detail::basic_config_file_iterator<char>::basic_config_file_iterator(std::istream&, std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool) in util.o
"Db::verify(char const*, char const*, std::ostream*, unsigned int)", referenced from:
  CDBEnv::Verify(std::string, bool (*)(CDBEnv&, std::string)) in db.o
  CDBEnv::Salvage(std::string, bool, std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<unsigned char,     std::allocator<unsigned char> >, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > > > >&) in db.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [litecoind] Error 1
```

I've been googling like crazy but can't seem to find a proper solution.

Comment: you need to install the boost libraries, specifically boost program options